# Unable to send email via SPUtility

Tags: development, web-part, email, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-email

I am trying to send email via SPUtility by trying the following code:

```
bool blnIsEmailServerSet = SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(web);
bool IsSent;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
{
    IsSent= SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, true, true, "alina@abcfoods.com.pk", "subject", "body");  
});
```

refer to the following link:
[Send Email from SharePoint](http://emailfromsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/04/send-email-from-sharepoint.html)

but, `blnIsEmailServerSet` is always getting `true` while `SPUtility.SendEmail` is always returning `False` in `IsSent` variable.

what is the issue?

Kindly help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my side and it is working with returned true bool value:
[image]

And email can be got when checking Outlook:

[image]

I think you will need to check your Outgoing email settings in your environment,specify the valid SMTP Sever:
[image]

Reference:

[Configure outgoing email for a SharePoint Server farm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/outgoing-email-configuration)

Comment: I've already checked the Outgoing email settings & they are fine

Comment: @AlinaAnjum, you could do a test with workflow sendmail action, check if the mails is working in your environment. This will help to narrow down the issue.